# Tensor Operation and gradient

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient, tensor, derivative

I was going some tutorials on youtube where below code sample was used to explain derivatives

## Create tensors.

```
    x = torch.tensor(3.)

    w = torch.tensor(4., requires_grad=True)

    b = torch.tensor(5., requires_grad=True)

    x, w, b
```

## Arithmetic operations

```
    y = w * x + b

    y
```

## Compute derivatives

```
    y.backward()
```

## Display gradients

```
    print('dy/dx:', x.grad)

    print('dy/dw:', w.grad)

    print('dy/db:', b.grad)
```

OUTPUT

dy/dx: None

dy/dw: tensor(3.)

dy/db: tensor(1.)

Could anyone please explain me how we are getting tensor(3.) & tensor(1.) as an output of gradient. I need to understand how pytorch is performing this operation behind the scene.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not PyTorch specific, it is just regular differentiation. I suggest you try do differentiate `y` symbolically by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `y = w*x + b`, then

```
dy/dx = w
dy/dw = x
dy/db = 1
```

Since you've not set `requires_grad=True` for x, PyTorch won't calculate derivative w.r.t. it.
Hence, `dy/dx = None`

Rest are the values of corresponding tensors. Thus, the final output is

```
dy/dx: None
dy/dw: tensor(3.)
dy/db: tensor(1.)
```

Comment: Thanks Harshit - I understood dy/dx = w,  dy/dw = x, however I am not able to understadn how we are getting dy/db = 1 ? could you please help.

Comment: if you differentiate y w.r.t. b, you'll get 1. [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=D%5Bw*x+%2B+b%2Cb%5D)

Comment: @ZKS when differentiating `d(w*x+b)/db` = `d(w*x)/db + db/db` =  0 + 1 = 1

Comment: Thanks Harshit for your help. Appreciate it.